# Android: How to use a large amount of Bitmaps?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, size, out-of-memory

I am drawing a frame by frame animation to a canvas and I have about 100 pics that I'm using to do this (which is about 1.5MB total). I started out by just doing this:

```
s000 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0);
s001 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s1); ...etc...
```

to every image and then drawing each image to the canvas:

```
c.drawBitmap(s000, X, Y, null);
```

to make an animation.

The problem is that I get this error "OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget". How would I load all the pics without getting this error? Is 1.5MB to much memory or do I have a memory leak? What would I do to fix the memory leak?

Thank you very much for your help. I am noob with android so could you please leave examples and not just tell me to do something that I wont understand :) Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this for every frame you draw:

```
s000 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0);
c.drawBitmap(s000, X, Y, null);
s000.recycle();
s000 = null;
```

This will try to release the memory after drawing the frame.

**EDIT**

```
myImgLen = 30;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
for (int i = 0; i < myImgLen; i++) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResource‌​s().getIdentifier("s" + i, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, X, Y, null);
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I have a new problem. My animation loops and I use the same Bitmaps over and over so if I recycle it then it gives me an error. At the beginning of my app I decode all the bitmaps like this:   int myImgLen = 30;
for (int i = 0; i < myImgLen; i++)
myList.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),    this.getResources().getIdentifier("s" + i, "drawable",
getPackageName())));    Do you know how I could decode each bitmap before drawing it instead of at the beginning?

Comment: I cant believe something as simple as recycling the bitmap caused me so much trouble. Thank you very much for your help, it is working now!!! Yeah! On a side note it is working but since it has to reload the bitmap on every frame it draws its a little choppy/slow. Do you have any tips/pointers on how I can make it more smooth o wise one :)

Answer (score 0):

Store your image into res->drawable-xhdpi make folder inside res folder.
For more information see this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: They are stored there(or in hdpi), but to draw them to the canvas I have to do this; Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.s0); to every one of them and thats whats causing the problem I think.

Comment: you have to make "drawable-xhdpi" folder inside res folder. Generally hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high). your image is 1.5 mb that's way you have to make drawable-xhdpi folder inside res folder

Comment: but my image(s) are a total of 1.5MB all together (and there are a lot of them) each image is 480x800 which belongs in the hdpi folder. I think...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the sizes of the images are incorrect. Refer to this answer: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966).